# What is the equation of the reflections of a fixed point across all the tangents to a fixed circle?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a fixed circle "**c**" and a fixed point "**A**" (in the plane of the circle), draw the tangent to the circle at a variable point "**X**" (movable, but constrained to be on the circle), reflect "**A**" across the tangent to obtain point "**A'**", what is the equation of the geometric locus traced by "**A'**" as "**X**" performs a full rotation on the circle?

[image: sketch of locus]

Comment: A sketch could help

Answer (score 2):

Take the circle given by
$$(x,y)=(\cos t,\sin t)$$.

We can assume that the point $A$ is on the $X$ axis: $A(a,0)$.

For each $t\in[0,2\pi)$, the tangent line to the circle is $r_t:x\cos t+y\sin t=1$.

The perpendicular to $r_t$ that passes through $A$ is
$$s_t:x\sin t-y\cos t=a\sin t$$

Now we compute $B=r_t\cap s_t$, I omit the details, since it is simply a 2x2 linear system:
$$B(\cos t+a\sin^2 t,-a\sin t\cos t+\sin t)$$
Now, 
$$\overrightarrow {AB}=(\cos t+a\sin^2 t-a,\sin t-a\sin t\cos t)$$
Since $A'=A+2\overrightarrow{AB}$,
$$A'(2\cos t+2a\sin^2t-a,2\sin t-2a\sin t\cos t)$$

Comment: Note that this is a parametrization, rather than an equation.

Comment: You can write the final result more-simply as $$(2\cos t-a \cos 2t, 2 \sin t - a\sin 2 t)$$ When $a=1$ (or when the radius of the circle is $a$), the curve is a [cardioid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid). So, a cardioid is the locus of reflections of a particular point *on* a circle through all tangents *to* that circle. Neat!

Comment: Eliminating the trig terms gives this equation for the curve $$( x^2 + y^2 - a^2 )^2 = 4 r^2\;( ( x - a )^2 + y^2 )$$ where I've taken the circle's radius to be $r$. Compare to the cardioid equation $$( x^2 + y^2 - a^2 )^2 = 4 a^2\;( ( x - a )^2 + y^2 )$$